# $rootScope async call in module.run

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with $rootScope assingnment while running it on module.run.

in module run there is:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', 'UserData', function($rootScope, UserData) {
    "use strict";
    UserData.data().success(function(data) {
        $rootScope.session = data;
    });
}]);
```

then, in any controller if used early:

```
$scope.user = $rootScope.session;
```

it is undefined. if used later - it contains required data.

I guess there is race condition, as callback from UserData.data may be called after controller is initialized.

I tried to $scope.$apply and $timeout ($scope.$apply have no sense here..) on $scope.user in controller and it have me no effect.

If I try to put $scope.$apply in app.run it gaves me

> digest already in progress

which is obviously true, as $http used in service by defauly calls $apply.

What am i doing wrong?

How can i provide data to all controllers in angular app? $rootScope cant work like i want, or I am doing something wrong? I see no way to update data in template/controller, so when the callback in app.run is called -data is filled.

Thanks for any help.

PS The weird thing is... when i console.log($rootScope) i see everything- even with session object with proper data, but when i try console.log($rootScope.session) its undefined.

EDIT: i found, that running $rootScope.$watch solves that issue, but its far from being DRY - putting watch in every scope variable that uses rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your object in some sort of container. For example:

```
$rootScope.cont = { session: mySession };
```

But a better idea is to not put the session on `$rootScope` at all. You could keep it in a state object inside your User service, and let controllers inject that service and grab the session.

Reading this: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html will help your understanding I think.

So basically if you want to stick with `$rootScope`, you should bind to your session in your controller like so:

```
$scope.cont = $rootScope.cont;
```

Then whenever you want to use your session object in a view, you need to make sure you start with a `cont` reference first, eg. `<div>{{cont.session.username}}</div>`

---

Also the reason why one `console.log` shows the correct information, while the other shows undefined, is because the debugger (chrome at least) will look at the object at the time you expand it in the console. Where as simply printing the value too early will give you `undefined`.

Comment: Oh! Chrome confused me a lot... I didnt know that. thans!
i will try both solution.

Comment: btw, putting it in container without $watch in controllers gives only empty object. $watch is still needed. I know how nested scopes work (i guess:) ). I thing the problem is with some data binding between rootScope ran in app.run and controllers, but im far from being sure.

Comment: My guess is that you are still trying to bind directly to the session. You definitely don't need a `$watch`, so I have updated my answer.